# ExpressJS not serving static templates using app.use

Tags: node.js, express

I have form that I am trying to serve as a static page using ExpressJS via app.use, but I'm getting an error.

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'public'));
app.listen(3000);
```

This is my folder structure

```
App Name
-node_modules/
-public/
       login.html
-package-lock.json
-package.json
-server.js
```

My error is **Cannot GET /login** when I go to localhost:3000/login. What can I do to fix this? It seems to work when I use template rendering using handlebars.

**EDIT**: I'm also running on windows 10 if that helps. 
          putting `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '**/public**'));` isn't solving the issue either.

Solutions:

1.

```
 const express = require('express');
 const path = require('path');
 var app = express();

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),{
    extensions: ['html']}
  ));

 app.listen(3000);
```

2.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html')
 })

app.listen(3000)
```

3.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

app.get('/login', function(req, res){ 
 res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/login.html");

}); 

app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: I believe you need to add **/** in front of public so its **/public** because **__dirname** will retrieve C:/<you rpath to directory>/App + public = /AppPublic instead of /app/public 

**edit**  [doc](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_dirname)

Comment: has it worked @DanT29 ??

Comment: @turmuka it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: I knew it wouldn't be the solution, that's why I asked @DanT29 is it your full code that we have there?

Comment: can you do a `console.log(__dirname + 'public')` to see the relative pathing? everything else looks okay.

Comment: @turmuka yes it's my full code minus the login.html file.

Comment: comment out `express.static()` function for now and try my answer

Comment: @Andrei it says 
C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\web\drone-apppublic

Comment: use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: @DanT29 one last thing to try.. the URL might need to be localhost:3000/login.**html** otherwise it might not bring up the result for just **/login** haven't done express in a while but I do remember it being really specific about serving static files

Comment: @DanT29 use the safe built in library path.join `var path = require('path')` as mentioned by @Ademola then `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

Comment: P.S: You should always use path.join or path.resolve for these kinda things, to enable express or any other library get the right location of the file. Cheers!

Comment: Go to `http://lcoalhost:port/login.html`

Comment: what do you get when you try to get to `:3000/doesItWork` path with my code @DanT29

Comment: @Andrei it works with .html at the end

Comment: @turmuka your code in the answers works but when i did the modifications after I get some errors

Comment: Nice, so we got it to work? what kind of modifications do you make? I can help you with the errors if you update it in your question @DanT29

Comment: `res.sendFile('login.html')` is wrong, my bad, `express.static`  is used for **server side code.** for example you want to link a css to your file you do `<link src="/myCss.css"` because it has the path you have specified from express.static. coming to `res.sendFile()` you can't do the same with it. you should do, `res.sendFile(__dirname + ''/public/login.html")`@DanT29

Comment: const express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(3000);

Comment: @turmuka That works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the official [document](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

as shown from the `console.log(__dirname + 'public')` you got **C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\web\drone-apppublic** which is the incorrect directory.

the safest way to do this is by using the path lib provided by node.js
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

**C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\web\drone-app\public\**

lastly because it's serving static files you need to include the file extension
I just tested it and it only works with `localhost:3000/login.html` if you want to remove the extension for html files you can add the rule to the static function as such

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),{
  extensions: ['html']}
));`

you can find the rest of the available function properties [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static)

Comment: is there anyway to drop the .html extension? If a user was navigating to that URL?

Comment: updated answer: added the link to the rest of the properties and an example

Answer (score 1):

If it says **`CANNOT GET LOGIN`** And tells you that it can not get to `login` directory, but doesn't throw an error, that means you haven't specified login dir in your `server.js` file

please add this piece of code before trying to go to the link again.

```
app.get('/doesItWork', function(req,res){
   res.send('it works!!');
})

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html')
})
```